# Diagonal Inputs Not Showing Up in Pygame Fighting Game Input Buffer

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a simple fighting game input buffer in Python using Pygame and I'm trying to get it as close to how actual fighting games work as possible. I've encountered an issue when trying to add support for diagonal inputs. I have a working version of the input buffer, and I'm looking for guidance on how to integrate diagonal inputs into the existing code. Here's the code for the program so far:

https://paste.pythondiscord.com/WWFQ

As you can see I've tried mapping the four diagonals to two keys at once, such as wa, sd etc but that just doesn't work as the inputs don't show up in the buffer, or it just chooses between one cardinal direction and the other. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

I've tried using sets to check for key combinations like so:

```
elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    key = pygame.key.name(event.key)
    if key in ['w', 'a', 's', 'd']:
        buffer.append(key)
    elif 'w' in buffer and 'a' in buffer:  # W + A (diagonal)
        buffer.append('wa')
    elif 'w' in buffer and 'd' in buffer:  # W + D (diagonal)
        buffer.append('wd')
    elif 's' in buffer and 'a' in buffer:  # S + A (diagonal)
        buffer.append('sa')
    elif 's' in buffer and 'd' in buffer:  # S + D (diagonal)
        buffer.append('sd')
```

but the images for the diagonals do not show up on screen. For example if I press down-back (S+A), the buffer just shows the input for up and the input for back next to each other, instead of the image for down-back.

Comment: So after some further testing, it seems that the code only reads diagonals after i press an attack input. For example inputting quarter-circle forward light then light attack will show up in the buffer as Down, Forward, the when the light attack is pressed it shows Down Forward so it snuffs out the attack input as well

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not an image.

Comment: There's a [built-in ring-buffer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) you can use instead of rolling your own. You need to process your buffer outside of the `KEYDOWN` event loop. Should insertion of a `wa` sequence remove the `w` and `a` events from the buffer? Do they need to be strictly sequential?

Answer (score -1):

The buffer check needs to be outside of the `KEYDOWN` event handler. A reasonable place is to add and `else` condition to your buffer clearance check.

Something like:

```
    # Check if it's time to clear the buffer
    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if current_time - last_input_time >= buffer_store_time * 1000:
        buffer.clear()
        special_move_executed = {move["name"]: False for move in special_moves}
    else:  # check the buffer for diagonals
        if 'w' in buffer and 'a' in buffer:  # W + A (diagonal)
            buffer.remove('w')
            buffer.remove('a')
            buffer.append('wa')
```

This is also assuming that you want to remove the moves in the buffer that combined to make the diagonal.
[image: Diagonal Moves]

You're not adding `i`, `j` & `k` keys to the buffer, so you'll need to add those for your special move detection to work. Note also that some of your special moves can't be detected, e.g., *Flame Punch* requires `down` + `right` + `light attack`, but the buffer processing will substitute `down forward` when detecting `down` and `right`. So I think you'll want two time checks for your buffer, one for diagonal substitution that only checks the last buffered key and another for lengthier inactivity to clear the buffer.

Detection of *Surging Heat* is possible without an additional timer:
[image: Special Move Detection]

Here's the full code listing, I replaced your images with letters or arrows included in System fonts.

```
import pygame
import sys

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Set up display
screen_width, screen_height = 800, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Fighting Game Input Buffer")

# Set up fonts
# font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)  # this doesn't include arrows
# grab the first installed font
font = pygame.font.SysFont(pygame.font.get_fonts()[0], 36)

# Load Input Images
if False:
    #Cardinal Directions
    up_image = pygame.image.load("up.png")
    down_image = pygame.image.load("down.png")
    left_image = pygame.image.load("left.png")
    right_image = pygame.image.load("right.png")

    #Diagonal Directions
    upback_image = pygame.image.load("upback.png")
    upforward_image = pygame.image.load("upforward.png")
    downback_image = pygame.image.load("downback.png")
    downforward_image = pygame.image.load("downforward.png")

    #Attack Buttons
    light_image = pygame.image.load("L.png")
    medium_image = pygame.image.load("M.png")
    heavy_image = pygame.image.load("H.png")
    special_image = pygame.image.load("S.png")
    
    
else:  # render fonts
    color = pygame.Color("turquoise")
    #Cardinal Directions
    up_image = font.render("↑", True, color)
    down_image = font.render("↓", True, color)
    left_image = font.render("←", True, color)
    right_image = font.render("→", True, color)

    #Diagonal Directions - 
    upback_image = pygame.transform.rotate(up_image, 45)  # ↖ isn't in the font.
    upforward_image = pygame.transform.rotate(up_image, -45)
    downback_image = pygame.transform.rotate(down_image, -45)
    downforward_image = pygame.transform.rotate(down_image, 45)

    #Attack Buttons
    attack_color = pygame.Color("firebrick")
    light_image = font.render("L", True, attack_color)
    medium_image = font.render("M", True, attack_color)
    heavy_image = font.render("H", True, attack_color)
    special_image = font.render("S", True, attack_color)

# Dictionary to Map Keys to Images
key_to_image = {
    'w': up_image,
    'a': left_image,
    's': down_image,
    'd': right_image,
    'u': light_image,
    'i': medium_image,
    'j': heavy_image,
    'k': special_image,
    'wa': upback_image,   # W + A (diagonal)
    'wd': upforward_image,  # W + D (diagonal)
    'sa': downback_image, # S + A (diagonal)
    'sd': downforward_image,# S + D (diagonal)
}

# Input buffer parameters
buffer = []
buffer_store_time = 0.4  # in seconds
max_buffer_size = 10
last_input_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

# List of special moves
special_moves = [
    {"name": "Flame Punch", "sequence": ['s', 'd', 'u']},
    {"name": "Tornado Kick", "sequence": ['s', 'a', 'u']},
    {"name": "Rising Uppercut", "sequence": ['d', 's', 'd', 'k']},
    {"name": "Surging Heat", "sequence": ['s', 's', 'k']}
    # Add more special moves here
]

# Flags to track if special moves are executed
special_move_executed = {move["name"]: False for move in special_moves}

# Main game loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # Add the key to the buffer
            key = pygame.key.name(event.key)
            # if key in ['w', 'a', 's', 'd']:
            if key in ['w', 'a', 's', 'd', 'i', 'j', 'k']:
              buffer.append(key)

            # Check if the buffer is full and replace the oldest input
            if len(buffer) > max_buffer_size:
                buffer.pop(0)

            # Update the last input time
            last_input_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    # Check if it's time to clear the buffer
    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if current_time - last_input_time >= buffer_store_time * 1000:
        buffer.clear()
        special_move_executed = {move["name"]: False for move in special_moves}
    else:  # check the buffer for diagonals
        if 'w' in buffer and 'a' in buffer:  # W + A (diagonal)
            buffer.remove('w')
            buffer.remove('a')
            buffer.append('wa')
        if 'w' in buffer and 'd' in buffer:  # W + D (diagonal)
            buffer.remove('w')
            buffer.remove('d')
            buffer.append('wd')
        if 's' in buffer and 'a' in buffer:  # S + A (diagonal)
            buffer.remove('s')
            buffer.remove('a')
            buffer.append('sa')
        if 's' in buffer and 'd' in buffer:  # S + D (diagonal)
            buffer.remove('s')
            buffer.remove('d')
            buffer.append('sd')
        # Check for special moves
        for move in special_moves:
            if buffer[-len(move["sequence"]):] == move["sequence"]:
                special_move_executed[move["name"]] = True


    # Draw the buffer and special move messages on the screen
    screen.fill("white")

    # Render the images for each key in the buffer
    x_position = 20
    for key in buffer:
        if key in key_to_image:
            key_image = key_to_image[key]
            screen.blit(key_image, (x_position, 20))
            x_position += key_image.get_width() + 5  # Adjust the spacing

    y_position = 60
    for move in special_moves:
        if special_move_executed[move["name"]]:
            special_move_text = font.render(move["name"] + " Executed!", True, "red")
            screen.blit(special_move_text, (20, y_position))
            y_position += 40

    pygame.display.flip()
```